# Webcam not working in dell

Tags: webcam

I am using Dell inspiron 13 5320 i7 with ubuntu 22.04 installed problem what I am facing is that when I launch cheese application only black screen appears same would be case for Gmeet.

Comment: try using vlc instead

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (Ctrl-Alt-T):

```
ls -l /dev/video*
```

to see the permissions (probably `crw-rw----`) and owner/group of the device (probably `root:video`).

Are you a member of the `video` group?

```
id
```

If "`video`" is in the list of groups, Stop Reading Now! This Answer doesn't apply.

If you're not a member of the `video` group, add yourself:

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Followed by a logout/login - group changes take effect at `login`.